# Getting error when I try to upgrade react-router v5 to V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I m getting typescript error when I tried to upgraded React-router-dom v5 to v6, How can I fix this typescript error. below you can find the code Thanks in advance

`

```
export function withRouter(ui: React.ReactElement) {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const routerValues: any = {
    history: undefined,
    location: undefined
  };

  const result = (
    <MemoryRouter>
      {ui}
      <Route
        path="*"
        element={({ history, location }) => {
          routerValues.history = history;
          routerValues.location = location;
          return null;
        }}
      />
    </MemoryRouter>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDYgi.png)`

below you can find entire file code
`

```
import React from "react";
import { Reducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { MemoryRouter, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import buildStore from "../redux/store";

export function withRedux(
  ui: React.ReactElement,
  reducer: {
    [key: string]: Reducer;
  },
  initialState: any
) {
  const store = buildStore(initialState, true);
  const dispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(store, "dispatch");

  return {
    result: <Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>,
    store,
    dispatchSpy
  };
}

export function withRouter(ui: React.ReactElement) {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const routerValues: any = {
    history: undefined,
    location: undefined
  };

  const result = (
    <MemoryRouter>
      {ui}
      <Route
        path="*"
        element={({ history, location }) => {
          routerValues.history = history;
          routerValues.location = location;
          return null;
        }}
      />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  return { result, routerValues };
}
```

`

I am passing history and location props which were work fine when I was using react router v5
here is the previous code :
`

```
const result = (
    <MemoryRouter>
      {ui}
      <Route
        path="*"
        render={({ history, location }) => {
          routerValues.history = history;
          routerValues.location = location;
          return null;
        }}
      />
    </MemoryRouter>
```

`

After update react router v6 I changed in my code because We know that v6 no longer support render keyword inside route So I Replace it

`

```
const result = (
    <MemoryRouter>
      {ui}
      <Route
        path="*"
        element={({ history, location }) => {
          routerValues.history = history;
          routerValues.location = location;
          return null;
        }}
      />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
```

`

But I don't have Idea in v6 How can I pass these props inside route

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
export function withRouter(ui: React.ReactElement) {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  
  const routerValues: any = {
    history: history,
    location: location
  };

  const result = (
    <MemoryRouter>
      {ui}
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  return { result, routerValues };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

1. The `withRouter` Higher Order Component/render function ***can't*** use the RRD hooks outside the router it is rendering.
2. `react-router-dom@6` `Route` components don't take "route props" and the `element` prop takes a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. The "route props" should be passed as props to the component being rendered.

## Solution

You'll need to create two components. One is a test render function that provides the `MemoryRouter` as a test wrapper, and the other is a correct `withRouter` HOC.

Example:
Create a custom render function that renders the component under test into a wrapper component that provides all the various contexts (routers, redux, etc)

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Wrappers = ({ children }) => (
  <MemoryRouter>
    {children}
  </MemoryRouter>
);

const customRender = (ui: React.ReactElement, options: object) => {
  return render(ui, { wrapper: Wrappers, ...options });
};

export { customRender as render };
```

See the RTL setup docs for more information on [custom render](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render) functions.

Create separate `withRouter` HOC to only decorate older React Class components that can't use the RRD hooks directly. Here's an example Typescript implementation.

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
import {
  Location,
  NavigateFunction,
  useLocation,
  useParams
} from 'react-router-dom';

export interface WithRouterProps {
  location: Location;
  navigate: NavigateFunction;
  params: ReturnType<typeof useParams>;
}

export const withRouter = <P extends object>(Component: ComponentType<P>) => 
  (props: Omit<P, keyof WithRouterProps>) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const params = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        {...{ location, params, navigate }}
      />
    );
  };
```